# Executing a package function works in SQL Workshop but not in Application Builder

Tags: oracle, database-schema, oracle-apex

**Background**
I’m using Oracle Apex to generate reports for a 3rd party SIS (student information system) PowerSchool which resides in its own schema, `PS`.
In `PS`, I have abstracted key business logic into a collection of custom functions in a single custom package – CKSD_Students.
**Problem**
In trying to access these functions from within APEX. Using the following single query as an example:

```
Select   S.ID As Student_ID
         , S.Student_Number As Student_Number
         , S.LastFirst As LastFirst
         , ps.cksd_student.get_student_enroll_status(S.Enroll_Status)
                                             As Enroll_Status
         , S.Grade_Level As Grade_Level
         , S.SchoolID As SchoolID
         , Sch.Name As School_Name
From Students S
        Inner Join Schools Sch
               On Sch.School_Number = S.SchoolID
```

From a SQL Workshop, SQL Commands windows in the `PS_Apex` schema this query executes fine.
In application builder when I create a test report and use this query for the content body query:

1. The query compiles (validates) without errors.
2. When run (blue start arrow) I get the following error:

   ```
     Technical Info (only    visible for developers)
   •   is_internal_error: true
   •   apex_error_code: APEX.AUTHORIZATION.ACCESS_DENIED
   •   component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_AUTHORIZATION
   •   component.id: 8270293315071117
   •   component.name: User still logged into PowerSchool
   •   error_backtrace: 
   •   ----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
   •     object      line  object
   •     handle    number  name
   •   00007FFCA77EF398       642  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
   •   00007FFCA77EF398       710  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
   •   00007FFCA77EF398      1014  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
   •   00007FFCC10C9B30       793  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_AUTHORIZATION
   •   00007FFCBE34C0A0      4518  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW
   •   00007FFCA89F3C28       173  procedure APEX_050000.F
   •   00007FFCA0EA4800         2  anonymous block
   ```

This error makes me think the problem is that SQL Workshop uses `PS_APEX` and the reports are using `APEX_050000`. This make sense because the views I have created in PS are not accessible from APEX until I granted select.

To try to solve this, in the `PS` schema, I have granted execute (and even debug in desperation) to lots of different schemas. The following is a complete list:

```
EXECUTE APEX_050000 NO  PS  CKSD_STUDENT
DEBUG   APEX_050000 NO  PS  CKSD_STUDENT
EXECUTE APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE NO PS   CKSD_STUDENT
EXECUTE APEX_LISTENER   NO  PS  CKSD_STUDENT
EXECUTE APEX_PUBLIC_USER NO PS  CKSD_STUDENT
EXECUTE APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER NO PS CKSD_STUDENT
EXECUTE NAVIGATOR_ROLE  NO  PS  CKSD_STUDENT
EXECUTE PSNAVIGATOR NO  PS  CKSD_STUDENT
EXECUTE PS_APEX     NO  PS  CKSD_STUDENT
EXECUTE PS_MGMT     NO  PS  CKSD_STUDENT
```

What have people done to access packages from different schemas in APEX? Can someone help me figure out what I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

APEX works in a different way.
All queries, packages, functions, etc. are run with rights of parsing schema. To see it, go to your application (a page with list of pages of the application), click `Edit Application Properties`, go to the section `Security` - `Database session`. There you will see a field `Parsing schema` - it is a main schema of your application.
You need grant rights to execute package `CKSD_Students` to this parsing schema, and then call this package as `PS.CKSD_Students` in your code.

Or, the second way, if you have access, you can log in into APEX `INTERNAL` workspace. There, in the workspace management section, you can assign the `PS` schema to the workspace of your application. After that all objects of `PS` schema have to be accessible in the application.